# Android listview update without refreshing startactivity

Tags: android, listview

I'm developing an Android app which looks like Facebook. `FeedsActivity.java` has a ListView which show user's feeds. When the ListView item is clicked, it starts the activity `ViewActivity.java`

`ViewActivity` shows one targeted feed. If user clicks the *like button* in `ViewAcitivity`, like count will be updated and then if the user clicks the back button, `FeedsActivity` will be shown.

I want to update ListView item's *like* count without refresh.

Here is my logic

**FeedsActivity.java**

```
onCreate(){
 // http request to get json feeds
 // parsing json
 // setAdapter
}

setOnItemClickListener(){
 // intent.putExtra() // FEED DATA
 // startActivity
}
```

**ViewActivity.java**

```
public void goBack(View v){
 // intent.putExtra() // FEED DATA INCLUDE UPDATE LIKE COUNT
 // startActivityForResult()
}
```

When I call `startActivityForResult()` in `ViewActivity.java`,  `onCreate()` of "FeedsActivity.java" is called so my ListView gets updated. (request json feeds and setAdapter) :(

I want to update only *like* counts, such as Facebook app.

Is there any other good way?
please help me.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at  [notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) of your adapter. this method basically tells the adapter that the provided data has changed and that it should update the `ListView`. so this will makes your `ListView` refresh and display new data